# I'm getting a null safety error on Future forEach

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm getting *The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'* on my element!['id'].

Code:

```
await Future.forEach(tempList, (element) async {
          if (element!['id'] == alertId) {
            alertList!.add(element);
            screenTitle = element!['subject'] ;
          
          }
        });
```

How to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the type of element before accessing it with []. It seems that it's not a map like it is supposed to be.

Moreover it's seems like you're using null check operator ("!") on a value that can be null. It is a good pratice to ensure that your value is not null before acessing it.

To correct that you can do it like this.

```dart
await Future.forEach(tempList, (element) async {
          if(element != null && element is Map<String,dynamic>){
            if (element!['id'] == alertId) {
              alertList!.add(element);
              screenTitle = element!['subject'] ;
            }  
          }
        });
```

I advise you to type your variables to be aware of what type you're using for each variable and avoid this kind of error.

Comment: Thanks. It works. 
I'll be careful about ensuring the value is not null before acessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your 'tempList' a List or a Map?
In case it is a List the way of calling a var named 'id' is `element[index].id`

By the way, be careful about using "!" without checking if the value indeed is not null, it might throw an "Null check operator used on a null value" exception.